# Book where a boy finds out that a building in his neighbourhood is the inspiration for a game that he is obsessed with

Tags: story-identification, horror

I am looking for this particular book which has the following details :-

- The main character who is a boy has a elder sister.
- He has a game that he is obsessed with and later on the book's plot, he realizes that a building in his neighbourhood shares its name with the game and is in fact the inspiration for the game.
- In the starting of the book, the character is shown to be playing the game and he defeats a villain (monster?) that he was never able to defeat earlier.
- He and his fellow classmates are assigned a project and they try to figure out if the building/mansion has ghosts or not.
- The building/mansion has been abandoned and the main character and his friends find it to be spooky.
- When the lot go in, the main character recognises the inside to be in accordance with the game he plays.
- While they are inside, they encounter some of the villains(monsters?) that are in the main character's game as well.
- While inside, he saves his friends from some monsters because he has already defeated them before. One of them is a Dancing Skeleton that will chase you if you look at it for too long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Goosebumps book, [Escape from Shudder Mansion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36127333-escape-from-shudder-mansion) by R. L. Stine.

[image]

> In an old-fashioned "trapped-in-a-haunted-house" story, twins Riley and Scarlett receive an interesting assignment from their teacher, Mrs. Stermon. Everyone in class needs to do a documentary video about an adventure, something exciting that they experienced.
> Mrs. Stermon gives them a suggestion, along with their friends Carter, Lee, Danitia, and Mia. She shows them a brochure about a scary old house on the edge of town, called Shudder Mansion. "If you six kids and your parents can stay there overnight, you'll all get A's," says the teacher. "I'll even give you extra credit."
> Just how scary is Shudder Mansion?
> It's terrifying.

The game is called *Escape from Shudder Mansion*:

> You have to understand. Shudder Mansion is so scary and so famous, there is an awesome, best-selling video game about it. The game is called Escape from Shudder Mansion.

The scene with the dancing skeleton is:

> “Oh.” I took a step back as a figure came into view. A skeleton. A human skeleton, lighted by dying sunlight from a window at the far wall.
>
> The skeleton appeared to stand on its own in the center of the room. Its toothless grin was frozen on its eyeless skull. I saw thick spiderwebs clinging to its rib cage. Its legs were spread, knee bones slightly bent. Standing there. Just standing there, bony arms hanging limply, nearly to the floor.
>
> I stared into the gray light. I’d never seen a real skeleton before—not even at the museum. What was holding the bones together? How was it standing upright like that?
>
> I didn’t have much time to think about it. I heard a rattling sound—and then the skeleton started to move!
>
> As I gaped in horror, it did a short dance. Like a sailor’s jig.